# Racing line following

Tags: math, 2d, physics, game-physics, racing

Let's say, there's a 2D racing simulator where we've got some sort of physics and a list of way points.
The physics is known, so we can predict car movement basing on given commands.

At any moment we have the current car state (position, velocity, rotation angle etc) and the next waypoint, which contains not only the position, but also the angle we want to be looking at when it's reached (facing the next waypoint). other parameters are less important.

My question is: what's the usual (or unusual) way to determine the sequence of actions the car needs to take to obtain needed position AND direction from any random state?

To make it simpler, let's say, we always move forward with fixed acceleration (we can't brake), so the only thing we can change is the movement direction (by limited angle per frame) and if the sequence of left and right turns is not enough to reach our goal from current state, we can count it as unreachable.

Comment: Is space discrete or continuous?

Comment: Search for 6 DOF path planning. In the simplest case, you just evaluate a spline.